# MySQL syntax error uploading database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I am uploading an existing database to phpmyadmin, but when I try to input the data I get this error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IDENTITY, acct_num varchar(25) NULL, acct_des ' at line 2

I am pretty familiar with phpmyadmin but I am not a programmer. Here is the data I am trying to input:

```
CREATE TABLE t_acct (
       acct_id              int IDENTITY,
       acct_num             varchar(25) NULL,
       acct_des             varchar(50) NULL,
       status               tinyint NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (acct_id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_asset (
       asset_id             int IDENTITY,
       fund_id              int NULL,
       acct_id              int NULL,
       emp_id               int NULL,
       chkloc_id            int NULL,
       cond_id              int NULL,
       type_id              int NULL,
       class_id             int NULL,
       storloc_id           int NULL,
       outdte               datetime NULL,
       duedte               datetime NULL,
       bcode                char(20) NOT NULL,
       notes                varchar(255) NULL,
       des                  char(100) NULL,
       model                varchar(30) NULL,
       sn                   varchar(50) NULL,
       recdte               datetime NULL,
       price                real NULL,
       curdte               datetime NULL,
       curval               real NULL,
       dep                  real NULL,
       deptype              tinyint NULL,
       image                varchar(255) NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       bin                  tinyint NULL,
       bin_qty              real NULL,
       wardte               datetime NULL,
       purch_from           varchar(255) NULL,
       consumable           tinyint NULL,
       salvage_val          real NULL,
       reord_pt             real NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (asset_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF20t_asset ON t_asset
(
       acct_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF21t_asset ON t_asset
(
       fund_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF4t_asset ON t_asset
(
       class_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF5t_asset ON t_asset
(
       type_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF6t_asset ON t_asset
(
       cond_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF7t_asset ON t_asset
(
       chkloc_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF8t_asset ON t_asset
(
       storloc_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF9t_asset ON t_asset
(
       emp_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_asset
(
       status
)
go

CREATE INDEX bcode ON t_asset
(
       bcode
)
go

CREATE INDEX wardte ON t_asset
(
       wardte
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_audit (
       audit_id             int IDENTITY,
       audit_name           varchar(255) NULL,
       dte          datetime NULL,
       status               tinyint NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (audit_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX dte ON t_audit
(
       dte
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_audit
(
       status
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_audititems (
       audititems_id        int NOT NULL,
       audit_id         int NULL,
       chk                  tinyint NULL,
       ubcode               char(20) NULL,
       user_id              int NULL,
       abcode               char(20) NULL,
       asset_id             int NULL,
       ebcode               char(20) NULL,
       emp_id               int NULL,
       lbcode               char(20) NULL,
       loc_id               int NULL,
       expemp_id            int NULL,
       exploc_id            int NULL,
       dte                  datetime NULL,
       status               tinyint NULL,
       bin_qty              real NULL,
       rec_type             varchar(1) NULL,
       asset_status     varchar(20) NULL,
       audit_reason     varchar(50) NULL,
       clear_table      tinyint NULL,
       notes            varchar(255) NULL
)
go

ALTER TABLE t_audititems
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (audit_id)
                             REFERENCES t_audit
go


CREATE TABLE t_bctype (
       bctype_id            int IDENTITY,
       bctype               varchar(50) NULL,
       fntname              varchar(50) NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (bctype_id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_class (
       class_id             int IDENTITY,
       class                char(20) NOT NULL,
       des                  varchar(80) NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (class_id)
)
go

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX class ON t_class
(
       class
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_class
(
       status
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_cond (
       cond_id              int IDENTITY,
       cond                 char(20) NOT NULL,
       des                  varchar(80) NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (cond_id)
)
go

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XAK1t_cond ON t_cond
(
       cond
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_cond
(
       status
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_curr_conns (
       curr_conns_id        int IDENTITY,
       comp_name            char(50) NULL,
       tme                  datetime NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (curr_conns_id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_docs (
       doc_id               int IDENTITY,
       asset_id             int NULL,
       doc_name             varchar(255) NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (doc_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF26t_docs ON t_docs
(
       asset_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX doc_name ON t_docs
(
       doc_name
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_emp (
       emp_id               int IDENTITY,
       lname                char(30) NULL,
       fname                char(80) NULL,
       mname                char(1) NULL,
       bcode                char(20) NULL,
       login                char(10) NULL,
       pass                 char(10) NULL,
       phone                varchar(20) NULL,
       altphone             varchar(20) NULL,
       notes                varchar(255) NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       ass                  tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       res                  tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       chk                  tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       sup                  tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       f_use                tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       mem          tinyint NULL,
       mem_ident_num        varchar(20) NULL,
       email            varchar(80) NULL,
       addr             varchar(255) NULL,
       category         tinyint NULL,
       emp_mem          tinyint NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (emp_id)
)
go

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bcode ON t_emp
(
       bcode
)
go

CREATE INDEX login ON t_emp
(
       login
)
go

CREATE INDEX fname ON t_emp
(
       fname
)
go

CREATE INDEX lname ON t_emp
(
       lname
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_emp
(
       status
)
go

CREATE INDEX mem_ident_num ON t_emp
(
       mem_ident_num
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_fac (
       fac_id               int IDENTITY,
       fac                  varchar(40) NULL,
       address              varchar(100) NULL,
       city                 varchar(40) NULL,
       state                varchar(2) NULL,
       zip                  varchar(10) NULL,
       notes                varchar(255) NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (fac_id)
)
go

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fac ON t_fac
(
       fac
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_fac
(
       status
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_fund (
       fund_id              int IDENTITY,
       fund_des             varchar(50) NULL,
       status               tinyint NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (fund_id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_hist (
       hist_id              int IDENTITY,
       fund_id              int NULL,
       acct_id              int NULL,
       cond_id              int NULL,
       fromloc_id           int NULL,
       loc_id               int NULL,
       fromemp_id           int NULL,
       emp_id               int NULL,
       asset_id             int NULL,
       dte                  datetime NULL,
       type                 varchar(30) NULL,
       bin_qty              real NULL,
       user_name            varchar(120) NULL,
       notes                varchar(255) NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (hist_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF10t_hist ON t_hist
(
       asset_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF11t_hist ON t_hist
(
       emp_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF12t_hist ON t_hist
(
       loc_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF13t_hist ON t_hist
(
       cond_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF15t_hist ON t_hist
(
       fromemp_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF16t_hist ON t_hist
(
       fromloc_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF18t_hist ON t_hist
(
       acct_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF19t_hist ON t_hist
(
       fund_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX dte ON t_hist
(
       dte
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_lbldesign_type (
       design_type_id       int IDENTITY,
       design_name          varchar(30) NULL,
       design_type          varchar(30) NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (design_type_id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_lbldesign (
       design_id            int NULL,
       ele_type             char(20) NULL,
       ele_top              smallint NULL,
       ele_left             smallint NULL,
       ele_ht               smallint NULL,
       ele_wid              smallint NULL,
       font_name            varchar(50) NULL,
       font_bold            varchar(5) NULL,
       font_ital            varchar(5) NULL,
       font_size            float NULL,
       text_caption         varchar(50) NULL,
       text_datafld_seq     smallint NULL,
       graphic_fname        varchar(255) NULL
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF14t_lbldesign ON t_lbldesign
(
       design_id
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_lbldesign_hdr (
       design_id            int IDENTITY,
       design_name          char(50) NULL,
       design_wid           float NULL,
       design_ht            float NULL,
       design_type          char(30) NULL,
       design_orient        varchar(1) NULL,
       print_orient         varchar(11) NULL,
       design_type_id       int NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (design_id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_lblref (
       design_type          char(20) NULL,
       seq_num              smallint NULL,
       db_field_name        varchar(50) NULL,
       descript             varchar(30) NULL,
       sample_data          varchar(50) NULL,
       design_type_id       int NULL
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_loc (
       loc_id               int IDENTITY,
       emp_id               int NULL,
       fac_id               int NULL,
       loc                  char(50) NOT NULL,
       bcode                char(20) NULL,
       stor                 tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
       notes                varchar(255) NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (loc_id)
)
go

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bcode ON t_loc
(
       bcode
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF1t_loc ON t_loc
(
       fac_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF17t_loc ON t_loc
(
       emp_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_loc
(
       status
)
go

CREATE INDEX stor ON t_loc
(
       stor
)
go

CREATE INDEX loc ON t_loc
(
       loc
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_misc (
       aclass               varchar(25) NULL,
       atype                varchar(25) NULL,
       afac                 varchar(25) NULL,
       aloc                 varchar(25) NULL,
       adep                 tinyint NULL,
       apurge               tinyint NULL,
       afund                varchar(25) NULL,
       image_folder         varchar(255) NULL,
       auditseq             int NULL,
       cust_ident           varchar(4) NULL,
       license_key          varchar(16) NULL,
       bc_prefix            varchar(3) NULL,
       bc_seqnum            varchar(20) NULL,
       relocate             tinyint NULL,
       arepair              tinyint NULL,
       app_ver              varchar(20) NULL,
       amaint_rpt           tinyint NULL,
       afindpop             tinyint NULL,
       amem             varchar(25),
       mem_show         tinyint NULL,
       cat1_nme         varchar(25),
       cat2_nme         varchar(25),
       cat3_nme         varchar(25),
       mem_fldnme1      varchar(25),
       mem_fldnme2      varchar(25),
       mem_fldnme3      varchar(25),
       mem_fldnme4      varchar(25),
       smtp_host        varchar(50),
       smtp_addr        varchar(50),
       smtp_user        varchar(50),
       smtp_pass        varchar(20),
       smtp_type        tinyint NULL,
       srv_int          int,
       amodnum          varchar(25),
       asernum          varchar(25),
       acond            varchar(25),
       report_folder        varchar(255),
       logo         varchar(255),
       display_emp      tinyint NULL,
       display_acct     tinyint NULL,
       semester_enddte      datetime NULL,
       frd          varchar(10),
       req_chkin        tinyint NULL,
       areord_rpt           tinyint NULL,
       adep_pref        tinyint NULL
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_res (
       res_id               int IDENTITY,
       asset_id             int NULL,
       emp_id               int NULL,
       loc_id               int NULL,
       fdte                 datetime NULL,
       tdte                 datetime NULL,
       notes                varchar(80) NULL,
       prio                 tinyint NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (res_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF2t_res ON t_res
(
       emp_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF3t_res ON t_res
(
       asset_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX loc_id ON t_res
(
       loc_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX fdte ON t_res
(
       fdte
)
go

CREATE INDEX tdte ON t_res
(
       tdte
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_type (
       type_id              int IDENTITY,
       type                 char(20) NULL,
       des                  varchar(80) NULL,
       dep                  real NULL,
       status               tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       class_id             int NULL,
       duedte_type      tinyint NULL,
       duedte_num_days      smallint NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (type_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX type ON t_type
(
       type
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_type
(
       status
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_user_defined_data (
       user_data_id         int IDENTITY,
       asset_id             int NULL,
       user_field_id        int NULL,
       user_data            varchar(255) NULL,
       dte_entered          datetime NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (user_data_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF24t_user_defined_data ON t_user_defined_data
(
       user_field_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF25t_user_defined_data ON t_user_defined_data
(
       asset_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX user_data ON t_user_defined_data
(
       user_data
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_user_defined_field (
       user_field_id        int IDENTITY,
       type_id              int NULL,
       class_id             int NULL,
       user_field_name      varchar(50) NULL,
       status               tinyint NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (user_field_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF22t_user_defined_field ON t_user_defined_field
(
       class_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX XIF23t_user_defined_field ON t_user_defined_field
(
       type_id
)
go

CREATE INDEX user_field_name ON t_user_defined_field
(
       user_field_name
)
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (fund_id)
                             REFERENCES t_fund
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (acct_id)
                             REFERENCES t_acct
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
                             REFERENCES t_emp
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (storloc_id)
                             REFERENCES t_loc
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (chkloc_id)
                             REFERENCES t_loc
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (cond_id)
                             REFERENCES t_cond
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
                             REFERENCES t_type
go


ALTER TABLE t_asset
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (class_id)
                             REFERENCES t_class
go


ALTER TABLE t_docs
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (asset_id)
                             REFERENCES t_asset
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (fund_id)
                             REFERENCES t_fund
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (acct_id)
                             REFERENCES t_acct
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (fromloc_id)
                             REFERENCES t_loc
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (fromemp_id)
                             REFERENCES t_emp
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (cond_id)
                             REFERENCES t_cond
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (loc_id)
                             REFERENCES t_loc
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
                             REFERENCES t_emp
go


ALTER TABLE t_hist
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (asset_id)
                             REFERENCES t_asset
go


ALTER TABLE t_lbldesign
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (design_id)
                             REFERENCES t_lbldesign_hdr
go


ALTER TABLE t_loc
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
                             REFERENCES t_emp
go


ALTER TABLE t_loc
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (fac_id)
                             REFERENCES t_fac
go


ALTER TABLE t_res
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (asset_id)
                             REFERENCES t_asset
go


ALTER TABLE t_res
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
                             REFERENCES t_emp
go


ALTER TABLE t_user_defined_data
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (asset_id)
                             REFERENCES t_asset
go


ALTER TABLE t_user_defined_data
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_field_id)
                             REFERENCES t_user_defined_field
go


ALTER TABLE t_user_defined_field
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
                             REFERENCES t_type
go


ALTER TABLE t_user_defined_field
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (class_id)
                             REFERENCES t_class
go



CREATE TABLE t_prov (
       prov_id      int IDENTITY,
       prov_des     varchar(50) NULL,
       address      varchar(100) NULL,
       city     varchar(40) NULL,
       state        varchar(2) NULL,
       zip      varchar(10) NULL,
       notes        varchar(255) NULL,
       contact      varchar(100) NULL,
       status       tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (prov_id)
)
go

CREATE INDEX prov_des ON t_prov
(
       prov_des
)
go

CREATE INDEX status ON t_prov
(
       status
)
go


CREATE TABLE t_maint (
       maint_id     int IDENTITY,
       type_id      int NULL,
       class_id     int NULL,
       maint_name   varchar(50) NULL,
       spec_inst    varchar(255) NULL,
       m_interval   real NULL,
       status       tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (maint_id)
)
go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IDENTITY` is a Microsoft SQL Server keyword.

MySQL uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` for similar functionality.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t_acct ( 
  acct_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  acct_num varchar(25) NULL, 
  acct_des varchar(50) NULL, 
  status tinyint NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (acct_id) 
);
```

Also "go" is a statement terminator in Microsoft SQL Server.  MySQL uses `;` or `\G`.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your quick response. I will try this!!